# Как указать родителя в конструкторе?

Tags: java

```
public class Solution {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Human.list.add(new Human("Макар", true, 60));
        Human.list.add(new Human("Люба", false, 55));
        Human.list.add(new Human("Петр", true, 40,null,null));//как здесь вместо null указать, что родитель этого объекта - это объект с именем "Макар" ?
        Human.list.add(new Human("Макcим", true, 60));
        Human.list.forEach(System.out::println);
    }

    public static class Human {

        public static List<Human> list = new ArrayList<>();

        String name;
        boolean sex;
        int age;
        Human father;
        Human mother;

        public Human(String name, boolean sex, int age) {
            this.name = name;
            this.sex = sex;
            this.age = age;
            list.add(Human.this);
        }

        public Human(String name, boolean sex, int age, Human father, Human mother) {
            this.name = name;
            this.sex = sex;
            this.age = age;
            this.father = father;
            this.mother = mother;
            list.add(Human.this);
        }

        public String toString() {
            String text = "";
            text += "Имя: " + this.name;
            text += ", пол: " + (this.sex ? "мужской" : "женский");
            text += ", возраст: " + this.age;

            if (this.father != null) {
                text += ", отец: " + this.father.name;
            }

            if (this.mother != null) {
                text += ", мать: " + this.mother.name;
            }

            return text;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `public Human(String name, boolean sex, int age, Human parent)` ?

Comment: @gil9red программа должна вывести на экран: Имя: Петр, пол: мужской, возраст: 40, отец: Макар, мать: Люба

Comment: При создании объектов родителей, положить их в переменные. Те переменные положить в конструктор детей

Comment: @gil9red а как при создании объектов родителей, положить их в переменные?

Comment: `Human father = new Human("Макар", true, 60);`, `mother` аналогично, а у ребенка `new Human("Петр", true, 40, father, mother)`

Comment: @gil9red Прости, но всё равно не догоняю. Куда конкретно вот это вставить? Human father = new Human("Макар", true, 60);

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Human father = new Human("Макар", true, 60);
    Human mother = new Human("Люба", false, 55);

    Human.list.add(father);
    Human.list.add(mother);
    Human.list.add(new Human("Петр", true, 40,father,mother));
    Human.list.add(new Human("Макcим", true, 60));
    Human.list.forEach(System.out::println);
}
```

Comment: а теперь понял, выносим "проблемные" объекты отдельно за список а потом отдельно их добавляем) Спасибо большое